# Error on Shuffling xml layouts using ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml

I'm new with `ArrayList`. I don't get it.

If I use `int[]` as the `ArrayList` item there is an error saying:

> The method put(int) is undefined for the type `ArrayList<int[]>`.

If I use int the error says:

> Syntax error on token "int", Dimensions expected after this token

I tried to use `add()` still the same... [image: screenshot]

Comment: Please give your code and what you have done so far.

Comment: First use `Integer` instead of `int` for creating ArrayList and second point is R.layout.<...> always return `int` instead of `int[]` Array

Comment: thanks @The Ice Mage. It goes this way.

ArrayList<Integer>mArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

  mArrayList.add(R.layout.layout1);
  mArrayList.add(R.layout.layout2);
  mArrayList.add(R.layout.layout3);
  mArrayList.add(R.layout.layout4);
  mArrayList.add(R.layout.layout5);
  
  Collections.shuffle(mArrayList);

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя Thanks I got it.

Comment: Last question. What could I probably do with (mArrayList, random)? Error says random cannot be resolved to a variable     public void onClick(View v) {
  if(v.getId() == R.id.button){

            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
     setContentView(Collections.shuffle(mArrayList, random));
     bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
     bt.setOnClickListener(Shuffle.this);
     
    }
            }, 0);
  }
 }

Comment: @leyrvo Just a friendly bit of advice since you must be fairly new to stackoverflow: when you have gotten a satisfactory answer on your question, be sure to click the big tick beside that answer to accept it. :) That way you can show the community what answer you thought was best, most helpful, etc. Also, it will "pin" that answer to the top of the answers section so that (in theory) people viewing the post for the first time will see the best answer. Theoretically as I say, and of course one answer being accepted doesn't mean the others are all completely worthless.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use primitive types `int` etc, as the "type" of an `ArrayList`. You must use the wrapper class `Integer` instead. Also, I stand to be corrected, but I don't think you can have an `ArrayList` of an array type for similar reasons. Perhaps `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` would work, as slightly ugly as that is?

EDIT: And while my Android experience is somewhat minimal and rusty, ρяσѕρєя K's comment about `R.layout.foo` always returning an int is certainly right.

Comment: Any x[] is a proper object, so you can have `List<int[]>` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this :

```
  ArrayList<Integer []>  mArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();           
  Integer [] layouts = {R.layout.layout1,R.layout.layout12,...};            
  mArrayList.add(layouts);

  ArrayList<Integer>  mArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  mArrayList.add(R.layout.layout1);
  mArrayList.add(R.layout.layout2);         
  ...
```